# Postgres sql error code for insert statement

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

A insert statement is generated in my java program that results in an error given as :

```
ERROR: @20111@
SQL state: P0001

-- Executing query:
 insert into C_OrderLine 
 (AD_Client_ID, AD_Org_ID, IsActive, Created, CreatedBy, Updated, UpdatedBy,
  C_Order_ID, Line, C_BPartner_ID, M_Product_ID, DirectShip, 
  QtyOrdered, C_Currency_ID, PriceList, LineNetAmt, Discount,
   ChargeAmt, C_Tax_ID, IsDescription, PriceStd, CANCELPRICEAD, 
   Iseditlinenetamt, Gross_Unit_Price,
        Line_Gross_Amount,
     GrossPriceList, grosspricestd, Manage_Reservation, Manage_Prereservation,           Explode,     EM_Cmcrm_Ispreferred,
     C_OrderLine_ID)
       values ('DB53D340E7284128884CDC972AFE0CF9', '8ADAE37C221E4579B54EF5744F753326',
    'Y', '2013-11-14 12:39:53.093000 +01:00:00', 'C9D3AAE3B95D4FFCAF5474ED8BAFD6AA',
     '2013-11-14 12:39:53.093000 +01:00:00', 'C9D3AAE3B95D4FFCAF5474ED8BAFD6AA', 
     '32F50B143DF145948990BCA5CEFC6279', '10', '1A80F57BAF63472CB5F38C33FBE23470',
      'D06C31E42DDF470CA684182BF8F15F21', 'N', '1', '102', '0', '20.66', '0', '0',
       '1A77590BECA54C9C86BE0D333023A0CF', 'N', '0', 'N', 'N', '25', '25', '25', '25',
        'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', '8EB102ACE8A74FE1A626098FB0EA92C5')
```

I took the insert staement and ran it directly and still only get information that it is error 20111.  Is there any way of getting more information on what is causing this error ?

Comment: Check the database logfiles for the complete error message.

Answer (score 1):

found out this is an error message comoing from a trigger function. Triggers are nice but they really do hide from the java code what is going on. Oke olved anyway